# Printing random array element in C89

Tags: c, random, c89

I have the following code that works fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>/*need this for rand()*/
#include "random.h"
#include <time.h>/*for time() function*/

int main()
{
    int arr[5], a = 0;
    printf("enter 5 array elements\n");
    scanf("%d", &arr[0]);
    scanf("%d", &arr[1]); 
    scanf("%d", &arr[2]); 
    scanf("%d", &arr[3]); 
    scanf("%d", &arr[4]); /*scan all elements*/
    srand(time(NULL)); /*set the seed*/
    a = arr[rand() % ARR_SIZE(arr)];/*from .h file*/
    printf("%d\n",a);/*print the random element generated above*/
    return 0;
}
```

It picks a random integer for an array of 5 integers.

I need the following modifications to it:

A function should accept two parameters — an array of void pointers and the array length. It should return a void pointer.

The function should pick an element from the array at random and return it.

int main() must seed the random number generator and then call the function. Then finally it should print the random element that was generated.

I don't know how to modify it to meet above requirements.

Here are the random.h file contents:

```
#define ARR_SIZE(arr) ( sizeof((arr)) / sizeof((arr[0])) )
```

Comment: What have you tried doing so far? And which part exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: What specifically are you having difficulty doing? You should create a new function with the requirements you described. What does the function look like when you try to write it, what part does not work?

Comment: The instructions for this assignment are as clear as crystal (honestly, probably the best instruction on a remedial assignment I've seen on this site in some time). If it is unclear what is expected, and more likely, how to do it, you probably need to revisit your reference materials in the course.

Comment: I need an array of void pointers and it should be of variable length. C89 doesn't allow variable length arrays and my malloc doesn't work with void array

Comment: Where in the assignment does it say a VLA is required ? It says the function you're writing should take an array (which ultimately just boils down to a pointer), and a length (count of elements). It doesn't even say the passed in array has to be *dynamic*. (and as far as the function is concerned, it shouldn't matter anyway, which is likely the point of the assignment).

Comment: _"My malloc doesn't work..."_. If you show the relevant code we might be able to clarify this. And why do you need an array of void pointers? And why do you need a variable size anyway?

Comment: Variable length here seems to mean "pass the length along to the function". Something along the lines of `void* func (void** array, size_t n)`, where "array" points at the first element.

Comment: For testing purposes, you could create an array of void pointers of the same length as your array of ints, and make each element of the array of pointers point to the corresponding element of the array of ints. Then you just need to write a function `void *get_random_ptr(void **array, int len)` that returns `array[rand() % len]`.

Comment: @IanAbbott "and make each element of the array of pointers point to the corresponding element of the array of ints" how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
void* getRandomElement(void** array, int size)
{
    int* arr = (int*)*array;
    return (void*)&(arr[rand() % size]);
}

int main(void)
{
    int arr[5];
    void* p = (void*)arr;
    printf("enter 5 array elements\n");
    scanf("%d", &arr[0]);
    scanf("%d", &arr[1]); 
    scanf("%d", &arr[2]); 
    scanf("%d", &arr[3]); 
    scanf("%d", &arr[4]); /*scan all elements*/
    srand(time(NULL)); /*set the seed*/
    printf("random element %d\n", *(int*)getRandomElement(&p, ARR_SIZE(arr)));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182176/discussion-on-answer-by-petar-velev-printing-random-array-element-in-c89).